# How to use different compiler in makefile?

Tags: makefile, gnu, ada

```
CC -c main.ada
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, CC -c main.ada, ...) failed.
make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified.
Makefile:13: recipe for target 'main' failed
mingw32-make: *** [main] Error 2
```

Using TADS compiler for compiling ada files in makefile..CC is tads compiler

Comment: Where in the TADS documentation does it say that TADS understands Ada? It has its own C-like programming language

Comment: its DDC-I’s TADS Ada Development System

Answer (score 2):

*make* cannot find the `CC` command. It must be in your `PATH` so that *make* can find it.

Possibly, `CC` is actually an environment variable and you forgot to write `${CC}` instead of `CC` to retrieve its value.

You basically need to look up in the documentation how you would call the compiler from the command line,

```
CC -c main.ada
```

seems to be the wrong way. Some quick internet lookup suggests that the command is actually named `tc`, not `CC`.

Comment: Like I said, figure out the command line that works and then make the Makefile use that. We can't really help you more with the little information you provide.

Comment: @trashgod Don't confuse Makefiles with shell scripts. Curly braces and parentheses [serve the same purpose in Makefiles](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Reference) – only thing to be aware of is that you may not mix them for that confuses the parser.